# KEYPRESS ENTER Imacros firefox doesn't work

Tags: keypress, imacros

What's wrong with this code? It is write a test, but it doesn't want to press the enter key.

```
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>LABEL>INPUT" CHARS="test"
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>LABEL>INPUT" KEY=13
```

Thanks

Comment: Not clear with your question. Are you trying to click some button?

Answer (score 0):

More details like site or htmlcode are helpful. Workaround is to press the 'Left Arrow' (=37) just before hitting the 'Enter' Key:

```
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>LABEL>INPUT" CHARS="test"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>LABEL>INPUT" KEY="[37,13]"
```